# Secure LUKS keyfile in root partition

Tags: linux, luks

I have 10 virtual machines with elasticsearch on VMware and compliance said that i should encrypt data volumes, the disk based encryption will be enough for compliance
i want to use keyfile to automount my LUKS partition with database data /var/lib/elasticsearch, but the main problem is that this file is stored on unencryped root partition, how to securely store it? i don't want to use USB stick with keyfile because i have 10 virtual machines with that crypted partitions, and if i encrypt my /boot partition, i should enter passphrase to boot OS, but i don't have access to GRUB console and to Vmware ( because i have only ssh access to virtual machines )
i think just to encrypt only data volume ( separate disk for storing elasticsearch data only ) and manually mount it every time if vm is reboot ( yeah silly solution ) but i don't wat to put password somewhere on systemd file to mount my LUKS partition
maybe other variants exists?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'll be happy to upvote this if someone can [edit] it and clean it up. It's 10 lines of text and not a single full stop.

Answer (score 2):

[clevis](https://github.com/latchset/clevis) and [tang](https://github.com/latchset/tang) software packages provide client and server side of what's called **network bound disk encryption**. They integrate nicely with luks and systemd and should cover your needs.

They are available in Fedora and RHEL and derivatives. If they are not available in your distro , I've provided direct links to their github locations.